# Deleting large data on live dB based on timestamp

Tags: postgresql

Looking for the easiest and efficient way to delete more than 20 GB of data from a production db (postgres) without causing load on database, based on (where clause) timestamp.

Comment: My suggestions it: do it as much as possible in chunks. Figure out what other filters (within that timestamp) you can use as separate chunks.

Comment: Any reason not to use LIMIT -n- and repeated calls over time?

Comment: We'll need a lot more information to give you anything useful.  Is it one or more tables, how is the table indexed, are there foreign keys referencing the subject table, etc.?

Comment: @Matthew it's two tables, and it's indexed on id and timestamp columns. No foreign keys.

Comment: @JorgeCampos any pseudocode example?

Comment: @DaveS wasn't sure if it would be efficient

Comment: You can't do it without creating load on the database.  You will have to describe what kind and amount of load is acceptable.  CPU, read IO, write IO, locking, WAL generation, etc.  Also the version.